# Not able call url from the function in nodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am trying to call the url from the localhost node JS server

```
router.post("/registration", function (req, res) {
    var request = require('request');
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
});
```

this url is called inside the function like REST API

```
Getting { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' } #1295
```

here if I can read anything from localhost, I am able to read the content or anything but internet domain like google.com or anyother domains are not able to get it

Comment: On what platform you are developing? Windows, Linux of Mac ? I wonder whether a firewall is blocking your requests.

Comment: google and other big websites may be blocking your requests for security reason since you are calling from outside, try your own domain.

Comment: i'm using node JS, my local network has proxy setup, will it be blocking or any setting to be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

later i came to know that that problem of local proxy settings